# Setting Firebase iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I'm trying to test my iOS app on my iPhone, but I got this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason:
>   'Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in
>   GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized options.'

My app was not released, so I just created the app in "iTunes Connect" but I didn't send any package because I'm still debugging. I did it just to get its "App Store ID" and to place him in Firebase's settings.  So, I replaced GoogleService-info.plist in my project with updated version. But it doesn't works.

My question is: how to set "App Store ID" field in Firebase if my App wasn't released yet? or How could I test my app in my device without this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might be getting confused between the Firebase App ID and the Apple generated App ID. They are two completely separate things. You don't need to create an app in iTunes connect to get Firebase working.

I'd suggest downloading a fresh copy of your GoogleService-Info.plist file from the Firebase console by browsing to `Project Settings > iOS app > Download GoogleService-Info.plist`. The value in your plist file for GOOGLE_APP_ID needs to match the App ID value in your Firebase console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was talking about App Store ID... I've updated my question...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would be helpful for someone who has to initialize Firebase configuration manually, not from the file.

```swift
// Works
let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")!)!
FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)

// Works
let options = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "EXAMPLEAPPID", gcmSenderID: "EXAMPLEGCMID")
options.clientID = "EXAMPLECLIENTID"
options.apiKey = "EXAMPLEAPIKEY"
options.bundleID = "EXAMPLEBUNDLEID"
options.storageBucket = "EXAMPLESTORAGEBUCKET"
options.databaseURL = "EXAMPLEDATABASEURL"
options.projectID = "EXAMPLEPROJECTID"
FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)


// Won't work. Let's be punished by default initializer usage. -_-
let options = FirebaseOptions()
options.clientID = "EXAMPLECLIENTID"
options.apiKey = "EXAMPLEAPIKEY"
options.gcmSenderID = "EXAMPLEGCMID"
options.bundleID = "EXAMPLEBUNDLEID"
options.storageBucket = "EXAMPLESTORAGEBUCKET"
options.googleAppID = "EXAMPLEAPPID"
options.databaseURL = "EXAMPLEDATABASEURL"
options.projectID = "EXAMPLEPROJECTID"
FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
```

Comment: I was having the same problem and this worked perfectly for me - thank you!

Comment: Seems works for me, but I didn't see the param "databaseURL" in my GoogleService-Info.plist file,  I used the value for "STORAGE_BUCKET".